# German characters ü ö ä Ä Ü Ö ß not saved properly in database

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

When users try to save their name in german, they're saved like this:

```
Markus MÃ¼ller ( Markus Müller)
Angela Eisenblï¿½tter ( Angela Eisenblätter )
Doris VÃ¶tter ( Doris Vötter )
```

I have inspected the values just before saving them with firebug and they show normally. But when saved they show like above.
The structure of my table is this

```
name    varchar(250)    utf8_unicode_ci 
email   varchar(250)    utf8_unicode_ci 
company varchar(250)    utf8_unicode_ci 
reading int(11)
rdate   timestamp
```

Please help me

**update**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","englisch_root","b00t","englisch_efront");
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
```

after i have added like this it give fullowing error
Warning: mysql_set_charset() expects parameter 2 to be resource,

Comment: Is the encoding of your source code files utf-8 as well?

Comment: Try to use utf8_general_ci for DB, all tables and all columns.

Comment: no i have done i just put in to variabel like this and save $name = $_POST['name'];

Comment: "prava" i have done as you have said now it dornt show jiberish like befor but now it remove germen charators and add english ones liek this "Markus MÃ¼ller ( Markus Müller) => Angela  Muller [now]"

Comment: What code are you using to save? If this is PHP you are probably missing `mysql_set_charset('utf-8');`.

Comment: $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","1f1fbb","englisch_efront");

Comment: mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);

Comment: after i have added like this it give fullowing error

Comment: Warning: mysql_set_charset() expects parameter 2 to be resource,

Comment: @Kombuwa it's old API use PDO Instead. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: @Kombuwa If you still want to go with old way you need to fire "SET NAMES utf8" query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` with `mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');` (or `$con->set_charset('utf8');`). You can't mix functions relative to databases of different PHP extensions ([mysql](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) vs [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli)): they work on different connections so they are mutually incompatible.

Notes:

- MySQL uses `utf8`, not `utf-8`
- never execute directly a `SET NAMES` statement, this is not safe:

> If you must change the character set of the connection, use the `mysql_set_character_set()` function rather than executing a `SET NAMES` (or `SET CHARACTER SET`) statement. `mysql_set_character_set()` works like `SET NAMES` **but also affects the character set used by `mysql_real_escape_string()`, which SET NAMES does not**.

([from MySQL's documentation about `mysql_real_escape_string`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html), the C function behind mysql(i)_set_charset PHP functions)

Answer (score 0):

First Read this http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html For clarity of encoding.

Then follow this article http://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql

You need to ensured that you are using UTF-8 encoding at all the places Including. Html page, Database schema, table, column collation, Db Connection etc.

Answer (score 0):

User table column data is in ASCII instead of utf8_unicode_ci.

Answer (score 0):

Using      `mysqli_query($link,"SET CHARACTER SET utf8");` BEFORE the query solved the issue in my case. P.s. i suggest using **mysqli_set_charset**.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues...

`SELECT HEX(col), col FROM ... WHERE ...` -- For "Müller", you should get `4DC3BC6C6C6572` if it is correctly stored as utf8.  If you don't get that, then you have either latin1 or a "double encoding", and fixing the data will be more complex.

If you are displaying this on a web page, you need a suitable  tag near the top.